# What is the difference between the JavaScript engine and the event loop?

Tags: javascript, v8, event-loop

I understood that the JavaScript engine operates as a single thread. And the event loop implemented in libuv was also known as a single thread. Therefore, I knew the JavaScript engine and the event loop were separate.

The event loop (mentioned in the official document and I know that it) handles the task contained in the queue (e.g. Timer, IO Callbacks, IO Polling...), but other documents explain that the event loop is the main thread.

So does event loop not only handle the tasks in the queue, but also the tasks in the call stack such as general functions, console logs, and so on?

I'd appreciate it if you could give me a clear answer.

Comment: check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) will helps alot

Comment: thanks a lot!! I'll watch the video